# Sql Query to populate insert and update date

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help in populating ins_dts and upd_dts logic.

Insert and Update date present in both tables so I need to know in coalesce if value is populating from `a.col_cmmt_txt, a.col_dscr_txt, a.col_annt_txt`, then use insert and update date from test1 table else if populated value from `b.target_col_desc` then populate insert and update from test2 table :

```
select 
    a.schema, a.table, a.column,
    coalesce(a.col_cmmt_txt, a.col_dscr_txt, a.col_annt_txt, b.target_col_descr) as coldscr,
    a.dw_ins_dts, a.dw_upd_dts
from 
    test1 a 
left join 
    test2 b on a.schema = upper(b.schema) 
            and a.table = upper(b.table) 
            and a.column = upper(target_col)
```

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): tables' definitions, some sample data and desired output with a description of the rules to get it. For this particular case you may add comments like "this should be updated with ... because ..." or "this should be inserted because ..."

Comment: You can use ```case statement```. If you provide your existing data and expected result, can help better

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like a `case`:

```
SELECT a.schema,
       a.table_,
       a.column_,
       COALESCE (a.col_cmmt_txt,
                 a.col_dscr_txt,
                 a.col_annt_txt,
                 b.target_col_descr) AS coldscr,
       --
       CASE
          WHEN    a.col_cmmt_txt IS NOT NULL
               OR a.col_dscr_txt IS NOT NULL
               OR a.col_annt_txt IS NOT NULL
          THEN
             a.dw_ins_dts
          ELSE
             b.dw_ins_dts
       END,
       --
       CASE
          WHEN    a.col_cmmt_txt IS NOT NULL
               OR a.col_dscr_txt IS NOT NULL
               OR a.col_annt_txt IS NOT NULL
          THEN
             a.dw_upd_dts
          ELSE
             b.dw_upd_dts
       END
  FROM test1 a
       LEFT JOIN test2 b
          ON     a.schema = UPPER (b.schema)
             AND a.table_ = UPPER (b.table_)
             AND a.column_ = UPPER (target_col)
```